# Post method Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.)

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework

I am trying to create new post from react frontend and I am getting this error.

```
Forbidden (CSRF cookie not set.): /blog/create/


# views.py
class CreatePost(CreateAPIView):
    permission_classes = (permissions.AllowAny, )
    queryset = BlogPost.objects.all()
    serializer_class = BlogCreateSerializer

# urls.py
path('create/', CreatePost.as_view()),
```

But when I tested my api with Postman, it created the new post without any problem.

I already tried other provided answers from stackoverflow but no luck.

Comment: By default, DRF applying the `csrf_except`, which means, there will not be any CSRF checks on the ***"DRF Views"***. Make sure that the front-end is calling the ***correct view***

Comment: Yes , you are correct I was making request to wrong url endpoint . Thank you for answer.